# RISCV debug tests - 'gdbserver.py' fails for missing module

Tags: riscv

When I try to run the following in the /riscv-tests/debug directory
it fails.

> ./gdbserver.py --spike64 --cmd ../../bin/spike

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gdbserver.py", line 10, in 
    import targets
  File "/home/dave/MyProjects/RiscV/build/riscv-tools/riscv-tests/debug/targets.py", line 4, in 
    import testlib
  File "/home/dave/MyProjects/RiscV/build/riscv-tools/riscv-tests/debug/testlib.py", line 9, in 
    import pexpect
ImportError: No module named pexpect

I have searched the entire RISCV installation for "pexpect.py" with no success. I installed the complete RISCV toolchain.  I can build code and run
the ISA simulator using spike and pk.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with my python installation. I found 'python-pexpect' in my Linux package manager and installed. But I am now having errors with other python system libraries.